# How to create 2D shapes with n-sides in WebGL using keyboard input?

Tags: html, webgl

I'm trying to create a program in WebGL that allows you to draw or create shapes of n-size via keyboard input. The user enters in the number of sides to generate a shape with that many sides. So,  if you press '3', you will get a triangle, if you press '4', you will get a square, if you press '5', you will get a pentagon, etc.

So far, I've been able to create seperate pieces of code that create triangles, squares, pentagons, etc. without keyboard input but I'm not sure how to go about generating shapes within the same program with n-sides via user/keyboard input. How would I go about doing this?

Examples of my code so far:

Drawing a triangle:

```
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
  '}\n';

var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n' +
  '}\n';

function main() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }

  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to initialize shaders.');
    return;
  }

  var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
  if (n < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
    return;
  }

  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, n);
}

function initVertexBuffers(gl) {
  var vertices = new Float32Array([
    0, 0.5,   -0.5, -0.5,   0.5, -0.5
  ]);
  var n = 3; // The number of vertices

  var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  if (!vertexBuffer) {
    console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
    return -1;
  }

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

  return n;
}
```

Drawing a square:

```
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
  '}\n';

var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n' +
  '}\n';

function main() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }

  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to initialize shaders.');
    return;
  }

  var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
  if (n < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
    return;
  }

  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, n);
}

function initVertexBuffers(gl) {
  var vertices = new Float32Array([
    -1, -1,   -1, 1,   1, 1,  1, -1,  -1, -1,
  ]);
  var n = 5; // The number of vertices

  var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  if (!vertexBuffer) {
    console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
    return -1;
  }

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by writing a function computing vertices positions for a polygon with the number of sides as param.

For example, this one computes the polar coordinates of the polygon within a circle of given radius. You can write your own one.

```
computePolygonPositions(sides, radius)
{
    let positions = []

    for (let i=0; i<sides; i++)
    {
        let i0 = i
        let i1 = (i+1) % sides

        let theta0 = 2.0 * Math.PI * i0 / sides
        let theta1 = 2.0 * Math.PI * i1 / sides

        let x0 = radius * Math.cos(theta0)
        let y0 = radius * Math.cos(theta0)

        let x1 = radius * Math.cos(theta1)
        let y1 = radius * Math.cos(theta1)

        positions.push(0, 0)
        positions.push(x0, y0)
        positions.push(x1, y1)
    }

    return positions
}
```

Of course, you can upgrade this function to add indices, tex coordinates, colors or anything you need.

Once you're done with it, just call it to create a new vertex buffer that you'll bind on ARRAY_BUFFER, set the layout and enable the position attribute.